# Small Beta weight equals small structural coefficient

Tags: multiple-regression

I have two predictors (X1 and X2) with large Beta's and large predictor-independent variable correlations (say it is like rs). In addition, I have another variable (X3; Beta=0.17; rs=0.18) which was not statistically significant in predicting the scores in the dependent variable. Last, I have an X4 with zero Beta and zero rs.

In interpreting this, should I only mention X1 and X2 are practically important predictors, while X3 predicts the scores at a lesser extent.
Or should I just skip X3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All predictors in a model are *important*, though they may differ in *strength* of prediction. Beta coefficients (or partial correlation coefficients) tell you of that strength. You should report all betas in your model whatever their size, because if you drop a predictor from the model, even the one with small beta, other betas can change sometimes dramatically.

The notion of importance is tied with the question of variable selection to a model. It has been a debate over what is the measure(s) of importance. Classical stepwise regressional selection procedures imply that it is part or semi-partial correlation. However, stepwise selection has been criticized recently. What is the IV "important" enough to be included in the model remains an open question.

Comment: So regardless whether they were statistically significant or not, they all predict the scores in the DV. 

What if the beta is small but rs is large?

Comment: Beta is small but r is large means that the predictor correlates with other predictor(s) which is stronger.